# Find the radical extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing the number $\sqrt[4]{1+\sqrt{7}} - \sqrt[5]{2 + \sqrt{5}} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, radicals

Find the radical extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing the number

$$\sqrt[4]{1+\sqrt{7}} - \sqrt[5]{2 + \sqrt{5}} $$

---

Wolfram  is saying that  the minimum polynomial is

$$x^4 + 12 x^3 - 42 x^2 - 468 x - 719$$

---

Definition of Radical Extension

A field $K$ is said to be a  radical Extension of a field $F$

If $\exists $ a chain of fields

$$F =F_0 \subset F_1 \subset F_2 \subset \dots \subset F_t=K $$

such that $i=1, 2 , \dots ,t_t$  ,$F_t=F_{t-1}(u_i)$ and some power of $u_t $ is in $f_{t-1}$

---

The answer might look something like

$$\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q} (\omega) \subset \dots \subset \mathbb{Q} (\omega, \sqrt[4]{1+\sqrt{7}},\sqrt[5]{2+\sqrt{5}} ) $$

Not sure what is the plan of attack. Do I find the minimal polynomial of the whole thing by hand. Can I split it into two? I am not sure how to do it without writing pages and pages of algebra.

Appreciate something to follow.

Comment: no algebra and no minimal polynomial at all is necessary

Comment: It should be of degree $80$. But you can just do all in a simple way.